# jQuery .html() fill a div with html/javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, html

I'm having this issue and I can't seem to get my way.

I use:

```
$('#DIV').html("<%=DIVContent%>");
```

The function DIVContent (.NET C sharp code) basically returns the contents of (a) page(s) dynamically. AJAX is not an option (cross domain) so it has to be fetched server-side. The server-side function also does the necessary stripping (replacing " with ' etc). This all works fine, the html gets into the div correctly.

Now I'm having a page with some jQuery code in it. This causes my .html(...) to break.
I've tried a lot of things, like htmlEncoding etc to make this work but no avail.

Can anyone tell me which steps I need to take?

Edit: also, the javascript error I get is: ulterminated string literal $('#DIV').html("........")
Edit II: Orbiting Eden did some nice out of the box thinking and it's solved now. Instead of filling the DIV with jQuery using .html() I now directly insert the contents using <%DIVContent%>. Credits to him for thinking differently :-) By the way, if anyone knows why .html() fails when JavaScript/jQuery code is inserted and how to tackle it.. Please do respond :) Thanks a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're adding server side code on the client side.  Insert the content, don't use <% at all.

Comment: This is inside the ASPX page, so I can access the server-side code. The server-side functions works and gets inside the .html(..) nicely. Only problem is when the page I'm including has JavaScript/jQuery code in it..

Comment: you mean your DIVContent is returning a full page with html tags?

Comment: why not you putting content right into the div on the server side ?

Comment: Does the html string you are inserting have double-quotes in it? You might have to escape those

Comment: Ideally you'd separate your JS from your serverside code, ASP in this case and use AJAX.

Comment: I used $('#DIV').load(URLHERE) and it worked fine. But I heard from the sysadmin I can't use AJAX, due to cross domain issues so I have to fetch the content of the page server-side. I think there's a difference between .load and .html in how it handles the jQuery code inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div id="one"><%=DIVContent%></div>
```

This is the most direct solution for you. After much thought, I can't see where you need javascript involved at all

Comment: The .ASPX page I'm using (where $('#DIV').html(...) is being called) already has the jQuery library included. I think the problem is that some characters of the JS code are breaking the .html(".."). Any info on that?

Comment: what precisely is the error? It could be something as simple as errant quotes which need to be escaped then unescaped on the client side. Try changing the " to "" in accordance with this thread: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=63801

Comment: I also do a .Replace in the server-side function. It replaces all double quotes to single quotes.

The error is: ulterminated string literal $('#DIV').html("........")

Comment: Ahh, I see said the blind man. I suspect the problem is how jQuery is rendered within jQuery. Let me try a comletely different approach in a few minutes ... OK, I just took the whole thing out of jQuery. You may still have to do something to work on how the quotes are treated.

Comment: Thank you Orbiting Eden!!! I was focusing so hard on finding the solution using jQuery .html() that I looked over the possibility to just inject it directly in the div using `<div id="DIV"><%DIVContent%></div>`. Wow, I was making it so hard for myself. It now works perfectly. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I tried, but it said I needed min. 15 reputation (I'm a new user). Don't worry, this post is bookmarked and WILL +1 you when I get 15 reps =) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is:
inside the $().html("") quotes, you simply cannot paste other double quotes. .. " " these ones.
this is because javascript will get confused if there are multiple :P

now, since I am not familiar with ASPX, I will give you the php code, just simply replace all " characters with: \" (a forwardslash escapes it)

```
$('#DIV').html("<?php echo str_replace('\"','\\\"',$DIVcontent); ?>");
```

Comment: The double quotes are already replaced by single quotes in my server-side function. This way, the .html("..") won't break. This works perfectly with only html in the page. Only when jQuery code comes into play it fails..